# Why does HashMap in java internally use array to store Entry Objects and not an ArrayList?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Why does HashMap in java internally use array to store Entry Objects and not an ArrayList ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is highly likely that `HashMap` needs to control how its internal table is resized according to the number of entries and the given `loadFactor`.

Since `ArrayList` doesn't expose methods to resize its internal array to specific sizes (`HashMap` uses powers of 2 for its size to optimize rehashing, but `ArrayList` multiplies capacity by 1.5), it simply wasn't an option to be considered.

Also, even if `ArrayList` did increase capacity in the same way, relying on this internal detail would tie these two classes together, leaving no room to change the internal implementation of `ArrayList` at a later date as it could break `HashMap` or at the very least make it less memory efficient.